# Find Command Syntax

Tags: linux, unix, find

I am trying to find all .rhosts files on some unix systems. I tried just -name ".rhosts" but we have a lot of really large NFS and MVFS systems that I do not want to crawl and I am having a hard time excluding them.

```
find / -name ".rhost" -type d \( -fstype mvfs -o -fstype nfs -o -name ".snapshot" \) -prune -type f -print
```

Comment: Where do you expect these `.rhosts` files to be? I'd expect them in users' home dirs, so you probably want to search in `/home` (or `/Users`) only, and maybe in `/root`.

Comment: In a perfect world that would work. However, our company has rapidly grown via acquisition, and consistency is not in our vocab. :)  I am just trying to be safe, so we want to look almost everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the manual page for `find` (should be on your system via `man find`, or you can readily find it online via a quick search). The `-mount` or `-xdev` options are what you want, although that will mean you need to run the command once for each local file system, rather than once overall, unless you want to craft an incredibly long line that `-prune`s each non-local file system...

Comment: I realize that...but I dont want to run the command x times for each system. Im going to put this in a script and run it on 2k+ systems. This is why i started to pursue the prune method for achieving this.

Comment: If you're writing a script anyway, then why not put in a loop over all appropriate filesystems? You might even get some extra performance if you run multiple `find` commands on different disks in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with.

```
find / -type d \( -fstype mvfs -o -fstype nfs -o -name ".snapshot" \) -prune -o -type f -name ".rhosts" -print
```